# Setting up vsftpd with users locked to specific directory

Tags: ftp, centos5, vsftpd

I setup vsftpd, and changed the chroot settings in the vsftpd.conf file.

But how do I make a user able to access only /var/www/html/username_here/

I made the user with useradd, but what's next? Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Look at the chroot_local_user and local_root options: http://vsftpd.beasts.org/vsftpd_conf.html

You can also get really restrictive by specifying cmds_allowed

Hope this helps.

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

Edit your `/etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf` file and add a line that says

```
chroot_local_users=YES
```

then restart your vsftpd

```
/sbin/service vsftpd restart
```

This will restrict local users to their home directories.